# Hide columns in excel

Tags: excel, hidden, vba

I am bit unsure whats the best way to hide columns in excel. I have a spread sheet with currently A to AL columns, but people keeps adding columns to it regularly.

Then we have a few user groups, production, designer,sales,revison and so on.

Depending on which usergroup the user is in, I would like to hide columns not relevant for the user.

So my idea is that I could add a note to each column header with the text production,designer if that column is relevant for those two groups and so on. Then in vba loop through all columns and hide the ones not relevant.

Hiding the columns are easy to achieve:

`With Range("C:C,F:H,S:AC")
  .EntireColumn.Hidden = true
End With`

and then either in a hidden sheet or a text file specify group name and the usernames such as:

design:kim,peter,kevin
production:arild,roar

Any ideas of how to best do this?

Comment: Either of your suggested approaches is fine. What are you expecting to hear from us?

Comment: If the idea with the note is a good idea, how can I loop through each note and get the value of the note?

Comment: This site is for programming enthusiasts. I suggest you try something and ask a new question about any specific problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample approach.
Say we keep a worksheet called *Roles* with the individuals name, the role they play and the columns to hide for each role:

[image]

The following is some simple code to:

1. get the name
2. determine the role
3. hide the columns in sheet *Sheet1*

```
Sub ColumnHider()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim uName As String, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, HideC As String
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Roles")

    uName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter your name", Type:=2)
    Set r1 = s2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=uName, After:=s2.Range("A1"))
    role = r1.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Set r2 = s2.Range("D:D").Find(What:=role, After:=s2.Range("D1"))
    HideC = r2.Offset(0, 1).Value
    s1.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    s1.Range(HideC).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

You would add some error handling to the code.  You might consider getting the name using *Environ("username")* etc.

Comment: Thanks Gary and @jean-françois-corbett, In my case i have around 50 users, and since the excel spreadsheet is still developing and all of those users are still adding columns to the spreadsheet I can not use: Manager:C:C since then when a new column is inserted at B:B there will be a lot of work to update all column references.  So I was wondering either to add a note on each column with the user group or a sheet where all the column header are listed with respective usergroup. Which approach will be the best?

Answer (score 1):

I am back from easter holidays and thanks to your help I solved the problem,

It has a sheet where the filter is defined, based on columns available in the list sheet. It saves the data in a dictionary so that it doesn't matter if users adds columns to the list sheet. Below is the code that other might find useful.

```
Sub filterCreation()

Dim lColumn As Long
rowHeader = 2 ' HEader row in list sheet
rowHeader2 = 1 'header row in filter sheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter")
lColumn = ws.Cells(rowHeader, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set columnHeader = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set filterDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim temp() As Variant

lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = rowHeader2 To lRow
lcolumn2 = ws2.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
If lcolumn2 > 1 Then
    ReDim temp(lcolumn2 - 2)

    For j = 2 To lcolumn2
        temp(j - 2) = ws2.Cells(i, j)
    Next j

    Else
        temp = Array(Empty)
    End If

    filterDict.Add CStr(ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value), temp

 Next i


tempCol = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(rowHeader2 + 1, 1), ws2.Cells(lRow, tempCol)).Clear


'Refill the sheet
For i = 1 To lColumn
'columnHeader.Add ws.Cells(rowHeader, i), ""

If filterDict.Exists(CStr(ws.Cells(rowHeader, i).Value)) Then
    b = filterDict.Item(CStr(ws.Cells(rowHeader, i).Value))

    For k = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
        ws2.Cells(rowHeader2 + i, k + 2).Value = b(k)
    Next k
End If

'column header to excel sheet
ws2.Cells(rowHeader2 + i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(rowHeader, i).Value

Next i



'Set columnHeader = Nothing
Set filterDict = Nothing

End Sub
```

In addition i also added automatically buttons to the list sheet to activate the filters:

```
Sub CreateButtons()
'On Error Resume Next

Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")

For Each wShape In ws1.Shapes
    wShape.Delete
Next wShape

rowHeader2 = 1
lcolumn2 = ws2.Cells(rowHeader2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

tempName = "All"
ws1.Buttons.Add(20, 20, 81, 36).Name = tempName
ws1.Shapes(tempName).OnAction = "Unhide_All_Columns"
ws1.Shapes(tempName).Placement = xlFreeFloating
ws1.Shapes(tempName).Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "All"


tempName = "ShowGUI"
ws1.Buttons.Add(120, 20, 81, 36).Name = tempName
ws1.Shapes(tempName).OnAction = "loadGUI"
ws1.Shapes(tempName).Placement = xlFreeFloating
ws1.Shapes(tempName).Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "Show GUI"


For i = 2 To lcolumn2
    tempName = CStr(ws2.Cells(rowHeader2, i).Value)
    ws1.Buttons.Add(15 + i * 100, 20, 81, 36).Name = tempName
    ws1.Shapes(tempName).OnAction = "Tester"
    ws1.Shapes(tempName).Placement = xlFreeFloating
    ws1.Shapes(tempName).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = tempName
    'ws2.Shapes(tempName).Characters.Text = CStr(ws2.Cells(rowHeader2, i).Value)
Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Filter]

[image: List]